# Firesbase auth fallback exception : Java lang exception

Tags: firebase-authentication, xamarin.android

Firebase Auth causes error if I set code shrinker to R8.
I am frustrated its been a week solving it, but i could not solve it.
'Unable to instantiate service com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService"'

*My Android Properties:*
[image]

*Full Error*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your `proguard.cfg` file you need to add the line;

```
-keep class com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService { *; }
```